# CRUD in Realm + RXJava

Tags: java, android, realm, rx-java

The thing is that I previously deleted and updated the records in Realm this way:

```
public <T extends RealmObject> void deleteDataById(String publicId, Class<T> clazz){
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {

            RealmResults<T> result = realm.where(clazz).equalTo("publicId", publicId).findAll();
            result.deleteAllFromRealm();
        }
    });
}

public <T extends RealmObject> void updateData(T object) {
    try (Realm realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realmInstance.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "updateData");
            realm.insertOrUpdate(object);
        });
    }
}
```

But since I'm studying `RXJava`, I decided to remake the `CRUD` operations under `RXJava`.

Here's how I write to the database:

```
public <T extends RealmObject> Flowable<RealmResults<T>> getAllData(Class<T> clazz) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmQuery<T> query = realm.where(clazz);

    if(realm.isAutoRefresh()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getData isAutoRefresh()");
        return query.findAllAsync().asFlowable().filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);

    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getData, !isAutoRefresh()");
        return Flowable.just(query.findAll());
    }
}
```

On the one hand, I'm thinking about leaving `Update` and `Delete` operations, since they do not return anything, but on the other, I think they should at least return the result of the operation. Maybe I'm not correctly presenting.

I tried with `Flowable.defer()`, `Flowable.just()`, but still an error in `flatMap()`:

> flatMap (io.reactivex.functions.Function>) in Flowable cannot be
>   applied to (anonymous
>   io.reactivex.functions.Function)

This is how I tried to make:

```
public Flowable deleteDataById(String publicId) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    return realm.asFlowable()
            .flatMap(new Function<Realm, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(Realm realm) throws Exception {
                    return realm.where(ServiceModel.class)
                            .equalTo("publicId", publicId)
                            .findAll()
                            .deleteAllFromRealm();
                }
            })  
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Questions:

1. Are my views correct with regard to `Update` and`Delete`?
2. How correctly to alter `Update` and`Delete` under `RX`?

Comment: I'll need to return to this question, but this is how I've done it before https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/master/simple-stack-example-mvp-fragments/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemoexamplefragments/data/repository/TaskRepository.java

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It seems to me that you also delete in the database without RxJava?